# How to make \CheckBox independent?

Tags: hyperref, itemize, textfield

i tried to create a pdf-Form using the hyperref package and the Form environment. This Form should include with multiple checkboxes, with the option, that many boxes can be selected at the same time. I've just been using the \CheckBox command so far, but the resulting Checkboxes seem to be dependent on each other, so that I'm able to check **only one** at a time. How do I change that?
The code i tried with kinda looks like that:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
Some Text.. and \TextField[]{Textfields}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=0.63 0.63 0.63,name=check1]{} item 1
\item[]\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=0.63 0.63 0.63,name=check2]{} item 2
\item[]\CheckBox[backgroundcolor=0.63 0.63 0.63,name=check3]{} item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal working document. Your code works as you would expect for me. Maybe this is a problem with your previewer?

Comment: Checkboxes are independent if they have different names - which is the case in your example.

Comment: Hello! I compiled your code, and I can select two or three CheckBoxes. Maybe depends of the rogram that you see the pdf's file. I use okular and it work fine.

Comment: See also `\MakeRadioField` (page 44 hyperref) and `\radioButton` (page 10 eforms), if only to **not** make a radio button by mistake.